# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"

Tags: 18.04, vmware-workstation

Keep getting the following error when trying to install VMWare 12.5.9 (VMware-Workstation-Full-12.5.9-7535481.x86_64.bundle) on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS:

```
(vmware-installer.py:13363): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

I've tried installing and reinstalling murrine engines. Tried the i386 version. Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a complete uninstall of VMware. Did a reload of the box. Ran the install again and it took. Not sure what was up originally but now the issue has cleared.

Answer (score 1):

This resolved my issue by installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module 
sudo apt-get install gtk2-murrine-engine
sudo apt-get install gtk2-equinox-engine
```